# Typescript definition breeze.d.ts - declare modifier not allowed for code already in an ambient context

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, breeze

Suddenly VS2012 stopped building javascript files from my typescript files. Options look ok. Also tried do uninstall web essentials without success.

Only when I completely restart VS the JS files are generated.

**Edit1:** seems that breeze.d.ts makes the problems. I am getting the error as soon as i reference it:

```
/typings/breeze/breeze.d.ts(213,5): error TS1038: 'declare' modifier not allowed for code already in an ambient context.
```

**Edit2:** also seems that typescript has still (v0.9) many bugs concerning references and paths.
For example you can't use spaces as you want

right:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

wrong:

```
/// <reference path= "typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

Comment: What messages do you see in the web essentials output window? Are your files under version control?

Comment: I use no version control. Output window says that it is compiling.

Comment: What are the versions of your TypeScript and Web Essentials? I sometimes experience this issue as well. In case I notice the compiler isn't working anymore I open the corresponding JavaScript files in VS, this usually does the trick.

Comment: I use the latest versions. Opening the js does not help.

Comment: just installed typescript 0.9 but still have the problem

Comment: Hey the error you're getting is because the breeze definition file uses the `declare`statement which isn't allowed. If you'd remove those statements, could you check again if you've still got the same issue?

Comment: yes this solves the problem. I thought that ts is also compiled with errors? This is not the case? ...please add this as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're receiving is caused by the fact the `declare` statement is used in the Breeze definition file, which isn't allowed. Definition files do not require the use of the `declare`statement to *declare* variables, modules or interfaces.

I've encountered similar behaviour where an error in one of my referred definition files caused Visual Studio to stop compiling TypeScript without throwing an error. I'm not sure if this is an error on the part of Web Essentials or the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get over this error by deleting a semicolon:

```
declare module 'asdf' {
}; 

 ^ deleted the above semicolon
```